# where does visual studio code store something related to project?

Tags: visual-studio-code

When I construct up a project ,and set some breakpoints  and so on.
So where these breakpoints and something related to this project are storaged ?

Answer (score 1):

**Project breakpoints** are placed in the `%APPDATA%\Code\Local Storage\file__0.localstorage` SQLite database (path for Windows), in the table `ItemTable` at keys of the `storage://workspace/<project_root>/debug.breakpoint` format. The values are JSON in binary mode (BLOB).

[image: ItemTable]

Part of my JSON for one of my projects (each element of the array corresponds to one breakpoint):

```
[
    {
        "uri":{
            "fsPath":"c:\\projects\\<project>\\lib\\root\\Angular\\Directives\\ListItem\\ListItem.ts",
            "external":"file:///c%3A/projects/<project>/lib/root/Angular/Directives/ListItem/ListItem.ts",
            "$mid":1,
            "path":"/c:/projects/<project>/lib/root/Angular/Directives/ListItem/ListItem.ts",
            "scheme":"file"
        },
        "lineNumber":7,
        "enabled":true,
        "verified":false,
        "id":"53a2ce47-36e2-44f6-9b9c-e47366a0802c"
    }
    // ...
]
```

---

I may be wrong, but I think that **something related to projects**, except for the workspace settings in `<project_root>/.vscode/`, are stored in this SQLite database. Also you can pay attention to the entire contents of the `%APPDATA%\Code` folder.